# How to $watch a variable in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I properly add a `$watch` function combined with a switch statement? I'm essentially trying to create one variable that works for my functions ( IE: `vm.clear()` ) and pass that to the DOM based on what is selected (IE: A or B).

So, selecting 'A' and clicking `vm.clear()` should set `{{vm.A}}` to 0, leaving `{{vm.B}}` alone. As well, selecting 'B' and clicking `vm.clear()` should set `{{vm.B}}` to 0, leaving `{{vm.A}}` alone.

```
<div ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput==='A'}" ng-click="vm.selectInput('A')">{{vm.A}}</div>
<div ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput==='B'}" ng-click="vm.selectInput('B')">{{vm.B}}</div>
<button ng-click="vm.clear()">Clear</button>

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectedInput = 'A';
  vm.A = '5';
  vm.B = '6';

  vm.selectInput = function(input) {
    vm.selectedInput = input;
    switch (input) {
      case 'A':
        $scope.$watch('selectedOutput', function() {
          vm.selectedOutput = vm.A;
        });
        break;
      case 'B':
        $scope.$watch('selectedOutput', function() {
          vm.B = vm.selectedOutput;
        });
        break;
    }
  };

  vm.clear = function() {
    vm.selectedOutput = '0';
  };

});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHT43o7NfjAqvP8h2XJg?p=preview)

Comment: Try `vm.selectedOutput = vm[input]` instead of switch

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why do you need a $watch for this?

Comment: @vp_arth I was able to get this functioning, I had to move my function into the other function. This then presented an issue that it no longer functions on page load because they're in another function which doesn't fire until one of the div's is selected. Any idea how to fix that? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/56vmhQGrKaO50YI6E53l?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an object instead of a value for A & B you can do away with some of the complexities of your code. I added an additional object called `selections` but you could just as easily do this right on the `vm` object. We add the name property to our two objects so that you can get the name in your view.

```
<div ng-click="vm.selectInput('A')" ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput.name === 'A'}">{{vm.A}} Select me</div>
<div ng-click="vm.selectInput('B')" ng-class="{selected:vm.selectedInput.name === 'B'}">{{vm.B}} Or me</div>
<button ng-click="vm.clear()">Clear</button>

.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selections = {
    A : {
      name : 'A',
      value : 5
    },
    B: {
      name: 'B',
      value: 6
    }
  }
  vm.selectedInput = vm.selections.A;
  vm.selectInput = function(input) {
    vm.selectedInput = vm.selections[input]
  };    
  vm.clear = function() {
    vm.selectedInput.value = '0';
  };   
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xQ5kVY8S2SaY209OPk8D?p=preview)

By using objects your able to have multiple variables pointing to the same object. When we change the property value of an object we are not affecting the references to the object itself.

In the picture below in the first case we have a & b both initially pointing to the string "lorem". Then we change a to point to "ipsum", but b is still looking at the value "lorem" so now a & b have two different values. 
[image: Pass by reference visual]
In the second case we have a & b both looking at an object. Although we change the property values of the object a & b are still looking at the same object. If we had done `a={value:"ipsum"}` we would have the first case again since were changing a to look at a new object.

Comment: I think I may be able to refactor my code to work this way, but I'm a little unfamiliar with how it works. Could you provide a little more information on what you did so I could learn more? For instance, how would I call this in the DOM {{vm.A.value}}? Also, is this now considered an array?

Comment: @nc45 I added an explanation of how this works. No it is not considered an array it is an object. I added how you would get the name in the DOM which is `vm.selectedInput.name`

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now why my initial solution wasn't working. This solved my issue.